# Sign CSR certificate

Tags: openssl, ca, csr

I am looking for a free Certificate Authority online, as I need it for my coursework. After creating the CSR certificate with OpenSSL I have to sign it with one CA of my choice. Do you have any suggestions of what CA should I use?

Comment: If this exercise is just for university coursework, then you can setup a self-signed CA using OpenSSL. Here's a good reference https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority to get you started.

Comment: If the use case is anything serious, then I recommend you to have a good understanding of PKI and its best practices. Have a look at existing solutions rather than managing your own in-house PKI.